# Making a search bar similiar to youtube.com

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to make my search bar static but one side adjust to the browsers width. Just like the one on https://www.youtube.com. Is their any way to easily achive this? If not how could i just make my search bar remain centered on my screen?

(I am using bootstrap 3 for my site)

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/lasquish/e0b66vy8/`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your div use style="Display:table" to get the search button to appear directly next to the search bar. With setting margin to 0px; on the bar and button itself. Then use min-width and a % width for bar size adjusting. And use `white-space:nowrap;` on the div to prevent the button and input bar from separating with a line break when width gets too small.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/e0b66vy8/2/

```
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group" style="display:table; white-space:nowrap;">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" size=60px style="margin:0px; min-width:160px; width:65%;"></input>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin:0px;">Submit</button>

        </div>
  </form>
```

If you want your search bar to not be at the very left side of the screen...
 You can use `margin-left:100px;` (or whatever value) to push it over from the left side. (Insert that CSS right after the `margin:0px;`

Answer (score 1):

yes, it can easliy be done with relative and absoulte postionning.
working example is [here][1]
https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/aBnbL

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/aBnbL
```

Comment: Hi Waqar. Please include the solution in any answers. Links should only be used for supporting documentation.